# "download-maven-plugin" - multiple files to download & relocation of output dir

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I've got a problem with the download-maven-plugin in Eclipse/Java-context. I got it running, but need help in two remaining points, I'm not able to find a solution for.

At first, this is my code snippet from the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution> 
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
        <goal>wget</goal>
        </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>https://testserver.com/svn/development/documents/Operations_Manual.docx</url>
                <outputFileName>Operations Manual.docx</outputFileName>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

1. I do not get a proper solution on how to be able to download TWO files instead of just one (same src-dir, same target-dir)
2. I would like to choose a target-dir, which is on the same level in the folder structure as the {project.build.directory} aka the target directory. I already tried something like:

   ${project.build.directory}/../src/doc

what of course did not work. Would be great if you have got a solution for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to use a download plugin to download artifacts which are used during the build? That sounds wrong...Furthermore this means your build is not correctly represented in your version control...

Comment: Hi, my setup is: a git repository containing all the code and subversion containing my planning documents, as well as the Releaseletter and Operations Manual, which I would like to inject into the final package.

Until now the two .docx-files are included in the git repository, which I wanted to unbundle, to be able to edit these documents simply by opening them in subversion. 

Was my idea bad? Are there any other possibilities to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved that problem already, just by adding one more `<execution> ... </exection>` task. That was the whole magic.

Comment: You also need to give each `<execution>` a unique id.  `<id>my-id</id>`.